# How to implement own custom list of country names for Java 8 Locale

Tags: java, locale

I have an application, that receives data from another API, which has some customer information containing, among other, country codes (ISO 3166-1 Alpha 3). This app supports multiple languages, in here, my first language (danish).

I need to display the country names on a html page, so i have created a `mapping` from the ISO-3166 country codes to locale to make lookups in, and it works great for getting the correct Locale. But the country names are not implemented in my first language, so when invoking `locale.getDisplayCountry(new Locale("da"));` the display country is in English. If i change the line to use a `Locale("de");` fx. the country names are in german as expected.

How do i implement a list of country names in my own first language, for Java 8 to use? (is it even possible?)

Comment: If you just want country names, wouldn't a simple Map suffice?

Comment: No. I don't want to add if-cases in my code, for each language. I just want natively to use the Locale as intended.